# How to linearise the constraint with a product term?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization, mixed-integer-programming

I would like to linear the following constraint
$$y\cdot \sum_{i=1}^{N}\mu_ix_i \geq M$$
where $y$ is a positive integer variable, $x_i \in \{0,1\}, i =1,...,N$ are binary variables, $\mu_i, i =1,...,N$ and $M$ are positive constants.

Thank you.

Comment: Clearly, the thing on the left is smallest when $y = 1$, the smallest positive integer.  Is there some reason you don't immediately take $y = 1$?

Comment: This is a stupid mistake. It should be greater than M.

Comment: When you say "binary variables", do you mean $x_i \in \{0,1\}$ or $x_i \in \{-1,1\}$?  I've seen both used under the term "binary variables".  Also, any chance the $\mu_i$ all have the same sign?

Comment: thanks for helping me clarify the question. :)  I have updated the corresponding statement.

Answer (score 1):

If $D$ is a sufficiently large constant:

$$\begin{array}{l}
\sum_i \mu_i y_i \geq M \\
0\leq y_i \leq Dx_i \\
0\leq y-y_i\leq D(1-x_i)
\end{array}
$$

Then $x_i=0$ forces $y_i=0$ and $x_i=1$ forces $y_i=y$.

Answer (score -1):

As long as the $x_i$ are not all zero, this inequality can always be satisfied by taking $y$ large enough.  So this is equivalent to $\sum_i x_i \geq 1$.

Comment: $y$ is also a decision variable in the optimisation problem. Maybe it should not be simply ignored.

Comment: @user363851 : How do we interpret "$y$ is a positive integer variable" differently from "we may make $y$ as large as needed to satisfy this constraint"?

Comment: In my case, $y$ cannot be arbitrarily large. For example, this constraint can be viewed as a ``ceiling'' function. Given $x_i$, $y$ is the closest integer for $\frac{M}{\sum_{i=1}^{N}\mu_i x_i}$.

Comment: @EricTowers There are probably other constraints in the optimization problem that involve $y$. Here we see just one of them.